# Can you use webpack hot module replacement with an ASP.NET MVC 5 application in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: webpack, asp.net-mvc-5, visual-studio-2019, webpack-hot-middleware

Is it possible to get webpacks hot module replacement to work using Visual Studio 2019 in an ASP.NET MVC 5 web site? I have seen articles and can get it to work with ASP.NET Core but I haven't found anything that will allow me to do this in an ASP.NET MVC 5 web application.